# [RAILS][sql] query to get the sum for unique values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Rails version:**

```
  @most_valueable_clients = current_user.clients.find_by_sql("SELECT vorname, nachname, preis FROM clients INNER JOIN treatments on treatments.client_id=clients.id")
```

**SQL Version:**

```
SELECT  vorname, nachname, preis FROM clients INNER JOIN treatments on treatments.client_id=clients.id WHERE user_id=1;
```

produces this in a table:

```
  vorname   |   nachname   | preis 
------------+--------------+-------
 hallo test | in ?         |   500
 hallo test | in ?         |    87
 ljkjölk    | lkjöljkölkjö |    50
 kevin      | marcel       |    50
 Hans       | bla          |    50
 Hans       | bla          |    100
```

I can use distinct to filter for unique values.
How do I create a sub-query that every preis( means amount) sums up for each user ? 
I need unique values with a summed up price.

**expected result:**

**unique clients with the summed up preis(amount).**

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you want to do is use `group by` in SQL. For Rails, try this: `current_user.clients.includes(:treatments).group(:vorname, :nachname).sum(:preis)`. I can't test this at the moment, but the fundamentals of using group is what you are looking for.

Comment: @nikkon226 Could you please create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad this worked for you:

---

What you want to do is use group by in SQL. For Rails, try this:

```
current_user.clients.includes(:treatments).group(:vorname, :nachname).sum(:preis)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
current_user.clients.find_by_sql("SELECT vorname, nachname, sum(preis) 
FROM clients INNER JOIN treatments on treatments.client_id=clients.id 
GROUP BY vorname, nachname")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not working got the following output: undefined method `preis' for #<Client

Comment: I'm agree with nikkon226 +1